# Taking my 2 month old bicycle from the US to India on plane as checked luggage. Do I have to pay import duty when I land in India?

Tags: air-travel, india, bicycles, import-taxes

I am an Indian citizen. Also, I will be taking my bicycle with me back to the US in August. The price of the bike is around $1600 and it isn't sold in India.

Comment: *The bicycle is obviously used

Comment: Although probably not relevant but is the bike required for some race or something similar?

Comment: Nope, just for recreation purposes.

Comment: IMO you won't have to pay duty because it falls in category of personal effects. Not posting an answer because I can't find any sources that category for Indians, only for [tourists](http://www.cybex.in/Notifications/72-98-Baggage-Imports-By-Tourists-6133.aspx).

Comment: @RedBaron That page says "could be imported temporarily". Is the OP visiting, or planning to stay in India and keep the bicycle there indefinitely?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan As per the question, he plans to take it back with him in August

Comment: As a general rule, temporary imports of personal items don't attract duty unless the customs officer disbelieves you and thinks you will not re-export it from their country. Even in the case that you are charged duty you can usually get a refund when you re-export the item. But I don't know the specific rules for India either.

Comment: Are you returning to your country of citizenship indefinitely?

Comment: nope, I will be going back to the US in august

Answer (score 2):

This is too late for the original poster -- sorry! -- but since this is a Q/A site it's worth answering. The [Indian customs for travellers](https://hcikl.gov.in/pdf/trvler-guide_ason22may2013.pdf) booklet says

> Used personal effects (excluding jewellery) required for satisfying daily necessities of life

are free. You can try to argue your bike is such but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Also, your allowance is 35 000 rupee which equals 487 USD. How much is a bicycle worth used if new it was 1600 USD? Hard to say.

If you feel it's much more than 500 USD then since you are temporarily importing a rather valuable good, the answer is an ATA Carnet. There are two companies in the USA authorized to issue them, [Roanoke trade](https://www.roanoketrade.com/) and [Corporation for International Business](https://www.atacarnet.com/). The base fee for a good under $10K will be 235 USD. You need to present your carnet outgoing to US Customs and when entering a country, go through the red corridor to show your carnet to the relevant customs authority.

Comment: For a temporary import of a used bicycle that was worth $1600 new, I wouldn't bother with a carnet. I'd just go straight through the green channel.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect this. I have no idea how they would calculate the used value of a bike.

Comment: In most cases, ATA carnets have restrictions on the reasons for the temporary import (e.g. for exhibition), though this varies depending on the country. It may also involve quite a bit of administrative hassle, like showing the merchandise to your home country’s customs or representatives both before and after your trip. Not sure there’s really an easy solution you can actually rely on, though.